# Nextcloud container can't be accessed

Tags: docker, nginx, https, nextcloud, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a nextcloud setup in a debian 10 VM with https and mysql and docker-compose but when I acces https://cloud.example.org my browser says it can't be reached. If I acces the link https://example.org it gives this page :

Example Domain

This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.

This is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
    nginx-proxy:
        image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
        labels:
            - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy=true"
        container_name: nextcloud-proxy
        networks:
            - nextcloud_network
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - /home/dev/nextcloud-data/nginx/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw
            - /home/dev/nextcloud-data/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw
            - /home/dev/nextcloud-data/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

        restart: unless-stopped

    letsencrypt:
        image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
        container_name: nextcloud-letsencrypt
        depends_on:
            - nginx-proxy
        networks:
            - nextcloud_network
        volumes:
            - /home/dev/nextcloud-data/nginx/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw
            - /home/dev/nextcloud-data/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw
            - /home/dev/nextcloud-data/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
        restart: unless-stopped

    mysql:
        image: mariadb
        container_name: nextcloud-mysql
        networks:
            - nextcloud_network
        volumes:
            - /home/dev/nextcloud-data/database/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql_root_testpassword
            - MYSQL_PASSOWRD=nexcloud_testp@ssw0rd
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
            - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
        restart: unless-stopped

    nextcloud-app:
        image: nextcloud:latest
        container_name: nextcloud-app
        networks:
            - nextcloud_network
        depends_on:
            - letsencrypt
            - nginx-proxy
            - mysql
        volumes:
            - /home/dev/nextcloud-data/data/html:/var/www/html
            - /home/dev/nextcloud-data/data/config:/var/www/html/config
            - /home/dev/nextcloud-data/data/data:/var/www/html/data
            - /home/dev/nextcloud-data/data/themes:/var/www/html/themes
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
        environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=cloud.example.org
            - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=cloud.example.org
            - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=root@example.org
        restart: unless-stopped

networks:
    nextcloud_network:
```

If I run this command :

```
curl -I https://example.org
```

The output is :

```
HTTP/2 200
content-encoding: gzip
accept-ranges: bytes
age: 427989
cache-control: max-age=604800
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Tue, 21 Sep 2021 18:33:43 GMT
etag: "3147526947"
expires: Tue, 28 Sep 2021 18:33:43 GMT
last-modified: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT
server: ECS (dcb/7EEF)
x-cache: HIT
content-length: 648
```

For command

```
curl -I https://cloud.example.org
```

The output is :

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: cloud.example.org
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An URL exists only only for us humans, machines work on IP addresses. When you point your browser to that address, your system actually makes a DNS query to find corresponding IP address and connects to that. https://example.com is a webpage IANA provides for documentation purposes, there is an actual system running the web service, that system has actual IP addresses, and to make it reachable there are corresponding DNS entries.

cloud.example.com can't be reached for the simple reason that nobody's providing any services reachable by that DNS name. Consequently there are no corresponding IP address, and no DNS entries. Since IANA has reserved example.com for documentation purposes, its subdomains like cloud.example.com are often used in training materials as, well, examples.

If you want to test using this DNS name, you can set up in your own intranet a server to provide some service. You can also set up your internal DNS server and create appropriate entry, or you can simply add the name and corresponding (private) IP address to the hosts file of the system you're trying to access it with.

Comment: Sorry for not sharing all the info, I did that and didn't worked, couple of restarts later and now it works, thank you.